# MySQL Trigger: Change column values on INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers, auto-increment

I do have the following table:

```
| uid (key) | version (key) | active | firstName |
|         1 |             0 |      0 | Piter     |
|         1 |             1 |      0 | Pater     |
|         1 |             2 |      1 | Peter     |
```

As you can see, the columns ID and Version create a combined key. ID is set as being auto-increment. Now I do have two issues:

1) I would like to increase the version on every insert I perform without reading the version value of the last existing row. 
2) I would like to set all existing rows for a given uid to active=0 as the record inserted should be the active one.

I tried to combine both steps in one trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_member_insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON members FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE version INT;
    SELECT MAX(version) INTO version FROM members WHERE uid=new.uid;
    IF @version IS NULL THEN 
        new.version=0
    ELSE
        UPDATE members SET active=0 WHERE uid=uid;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO members(version) VALUES(new.version);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

but my MySQL server just says:

#1064 - Error in SQL syntax at .version=0
    ELSE
        UPDATE members SET active=0 WHERE uid=uid;
    END I in row 8

Is it possible to achieve my goals by using a trigger? How do I need to change it so that it works?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it neccessary to store version? It seems like it would be simpler to store a simple AI. We could always calculate version (and active) if necessary.

Comment: Where does @version come from? Please add your table definitions and the trigger code.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to store the version to have an idea of the sequence. Also, any of these versions could be the active one (e.g. when the last one is incorrect).
I stated the SQL command I fired and which caused the version error: insert into members (uid, active, firstName) VALUES (1, 1, 'Peter')

Comment: I don't follow; Either the 'record inserted [is] the active one', or, it isn;t.

Comment: OK, I rephrased my question.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I'd just do this, and leave it at that...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,uid  INT NOT NULL
,firstName VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (uid,firstname) VALUES
(1,'Piter'),
(1,'Pater'),
(1,'Peter');

SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT MAX(id) id FROM my_table GROUP BY uid ) y
    ON y.id = x.id;

+----+-----+-----------+
| id | uid | firstName |
+----+-----+-----------+
|  3 |   1 | Peter     |
+----+-----+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi Strawberry, you are setting the uid yourself but this is an unknown number if the row is new. Therefore I was thinking of two AI fields but this is not supported by the MySQL server I have to use.

Comment: @AntonSack Sorry, I don't see the relevance of that argument. You're welcome to edit your question, extending the example I've provided above in order to prove/explicate your point.

Comment: Any row could be the active one. It does not have to be the one with the highest "version" number.

Comment: Yes it does. You said at the outset that you only do INSERTs.

Comment: Touché. I wanted to say that rows are always added. The only think which is updated is the active flag.